# Setting global environment variables in Jenkinsfile on Windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I a have Jenkins CI server running on top of a Windows system, and now I would like to set global environment variables for my pipeline.

I tried two different ways both without success:

```
node {
    environment {
        MY_PYTHON='D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'
        PATH='%MY_PYTHON%;%MY_PYTHON%\Scripts;%PATH%'
    }
    stage ('Checkout and Build') {
        bat 'echo %MY_PYTHON%'
        bat 'echo %PATH%'
        bat 'python --version'
    }
}
```

After starting the build it throws the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

WorkflowScript: 3: unexpected char: '\' @ line 3, column 22.

           MY_PYTHON='D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'

                        ^
```

Kinda straightforward so I tried doubling the backslashes like this:

```
environment {
    MY_PYTHON='D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3'
    PATH='%MY_PYTHON%;%MY_PYTHON%\\Scripts;%PATH%'
}
```

So after restarting the build I got error only for the command `python --version` as `python` still cannot be found on path, and also I get back nothing for `MY_PYTHON` and for `PATH` I get all the predifined paths except those I wanted to add.

Got stuck, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
environment {
    MY_PYTHON='D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'
    PATH='%MY_PYTHON%;%MY_PYTHON%\Scripts;%PATH%' <----
}
```

I don't think Jenkins is capable of expanding variables in the environment block and I think it is leaving your PATH variable completely empty. You can check this by adding the step `bat 'set'` which prints all environment variables in Windows. I tried it and  Jenkins actually fails to execute `set` because PATH must be empty.

For you case, maybe you would prefer to do something like:

```
node {
    environment {
        MY_PYTHON='D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3'
    }
    stage ('Checkout and Build') {
        bat '%MY_PYTHON%\\python --version'
    }
}
```

(I am not a python developer, so I am not sure if that path would actually be correct).

I also have noted that you can use variables as follows:

- `bat 'echo var: %VARIABLE_NAME%'` <-- single quote, %var% for variable
- `bat "echo var: $VARIABLE_NAME"` <-- double quote, $var for variable

The combination of single quote and `$var` doesn't seem to work, I assume the double quote makes Jenkins expand the variable (as a Groovy variable, I guess) instead of the operating system.

Comment: Correct! Here, `bat "echo var: $VARIABLE_NAME"` is interpreted as a Groovy GString and hence interpolated by Groovy and not the OS. Nevertheless, on Windows, `%VARIABLE_NAME%` should work with either single or double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a variable you have to use the double quotes:

```
PATH="${MY_PYTHON};${MY_PYTHON}\Scripts;${PATH}"
```

Regardless of that, looks like there is a problem in particular to set the PATH in windows, as "PATH" is also a command.

What you have to do is something like this:

```
node {
    environment {
        MY_PYTHON='D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'
    }
    stage ('Checkout and Build') {
        bat '''
            set PATH = "%MY_PYTHON%;%MY_PYTHON%\Scripts;%PATH%"
            echo %MY_PYTHON%
            echo %PATH%
            python --version
        '''
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that : MY_PYTHON='D:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3'